# Can I run two versions of Opera with independent cookies?

Tags: opera, cookies

I'd like to have multiple Opera windows open, each using a separate cookie jar.  This is primarily so I can be connected to both my personal google email and my work google docs account at the same time.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to run two instances of Opera for that. Just open a private tab (right click on the tabs bar and select the "new private tab" option) and load your personal email there, then right click on it and "pin tab".

Answer (score 2):

Setting up multiple profiles is the best solution. They will use the same Opera instance so you won't have to update different directories manually when a new version is out, and a new profile doesn't use as much place on your hard drive as a complete copy of Opera.
[Tutorials](http://operawiki.info/operaprofiles) of how this can be done can be found [all around the internet](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/opera-profile-creator) (I prefer [the -pd way](http://my.opera.com/ruario/blog/2011/09/28/the-pd-personal-directory-switch))

(Or alternatively you can do what I do... using Opera with my personal Gmail account and using Opera Next with my work account. But this should be considered a bad idea because Opera Next can be quite instable.)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/opera_portable) version of Opera should work; all the settings are supposed to be kept separate. And you could even make multiple copies if you need more than two.

Only drawback is that you might only be able to run one at a time. Just have to test it and see.